# VC++ equivalent for asm jmp

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86

I have a lot of old code in the form:

```
FARPROC p[1024];

...


__asm {
   jmp p[128];
}
```

This worked well for 32-bit applications, but upgrading to 64-bit where inline `asm` is no longer supported.

Is there an equivalent `jmp` function in C++?

Comment: `FARPROC`? I'm glad I'm not in your shoes.

Comment: Maybe goto [(at least with gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)

Comment: Put it out of its misery.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to specify the compiler. I assume its MSVC's 64bit ASM limitation..

Comment: This question sounds pretty much the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6421433/2189500).  There are some ideas there (including a reference to [threaded code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code), but no silver bullets.

Answer (score 0):

While MSVC won't let you compile ASM, you can instead compile the ASM using MASM and then link against it. There is a fairly comprehensive example of how to do the complete setup [here](http://www.sciencezero.org/index.php?title=How_to_write_x64_assembly_functions_in_Visual_C%2B%2B).

From what I can tell you're just trying to invoke a function, in which case invoking functions using the actual language might be a better avenue to consider.

Comment: IIRC `call` will push the return address onto the stack while `jmp` does not so I don't think you can simply treat it like a function.

Comment: @MegaStupidMonkeys You are correct, jumping is not the same thing as a function call (unless that call gets inlined...), but basically the guy is jumping around code, which is the traditional purpose of functions!

Answer (score 0):

i didn't use it ever but there is goto function still.