# Python computed gotos and USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, cpython

Since Python 3.2, Computed gotos are enabled by default: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#build-and-c-api-changes)

> Computed gotos are now enabled by default on supported compilers (which are detected by the configure script). They can still be disabled selectively by specifying `--without-computed-gotos`.

However on Mac, installed Python does not have computed gotos enabled.

```
# Tested on macOS 10.15.3, with pyenv installed Python 3.7, 3.8

import sysconfig

sysconfig.get_config_var('USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS') # outputs: 0   
sysconfig.get_config_var('HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS')  # outputs: 1
```

I'm guessing it's because the compiler used (Clang by default) doesn't support this feature. Is there anyway to get around it?

---

**Update: I created [bpo-40790](https://bugs.python.org/issue40790) for this issue.**

Comment: I'm under the impression clang optimizes the switch statement into something equivalent to computed gotos so, for clang at least, this might be 0 unless explicitly configured with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, I made the wrong assumption in the question. It turns out that, **Python does have computed gotos enabled on Mac**. I put up a [simple script](https://gist.github.com/laike9m/861c67b6341d946822a44e37822e9efc) that can detect it in a reliable way.

Now we have a new question: what's all about `USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS` and `HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS`?

The conclusion is:

**Neither `sysconfig.get_config_var('USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS')` or `sysconfig.get_config_var('HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS')` can indicate whether computed gotos is actually enabled.**

To demonstrate it, I manaully compiled CPython 3.7 and 3.8 with no flag, `--without-computed-gotos` and `--with-computed-gotos`, then test the bebavior between different installations using the aforementioned script. Here's the result:

[image]

Based on the result and my guesses, it seems

- `USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS`: is for detecting whether `--with-computed-gotos` is set when compiling.
- `HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS`: is for detecting whether the compiler used supports it.

On Windows, since [MSVC doesn't support label as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421433/address-of-labels-msvc), the behavior makes sense.

I also read the configure script and ceval.c, but still don't fully understand how everything works.