# How to pass label in PHP?

Tags: php, lambda, goto

*The background of this story is pretty long, so to keep things short -- I know goto is bad, but I have no other choice, because... PHP lacks comma operator.*

I have such pattern -- regular function with entry point given as label, and inside it a small lambda which needs to `goto` to that entry point. Something like this (incorrect code):

```
  function water()
  {
    _Entry_point_2_0:
    // ... some code
    (function() { /*...*/ ;goto _Entry_point_2_0;})();
    // ... some code
  }
```

I cannot just jump across the function boundaries, so my next idea is to return the label from the lambda and use it as "value" for goto. Something like this:

```
  function water()
  {
    _Entry_point_2_0:
    // ... some code
    goto (function() { /*...*/ ;return '_Entry_point_2_0';})();
    // ... some code
  }
```

This does not work. Evaluating entire `goto` as a string `eval ('goto _Entry_point_2_0;')` does not work either.

The crazy part is I know the label in advance, so you can ask why I cannot write entire function like that:

```
  function water()
  {
    _Entry_point_2_0:
    // ... some code
    (function() { /*...*/ ;})();
    goto _Entry_point_2_0;
    // ... some code
  }
```

The problem is in logic -- executing lambda **and** goto make 2 expressions now, not one. And I need to make it in one expression -- execute lambda and goto has to be packed in single expression.

I also cannot call recursively the main function because it is whole point of this work, to avoid recursive call :-).

What are the other ways to achieve this?

**UPDATE 1** Maybe I rephrase -- what I would like to achieve with goto is `continue my_function`. Executed from or at the boundary of the inner function (i.e. lambda).

**UPDATE 2** The main goal is to loop over the main function, so it is almost equivalent to:

```
  function water()
  {
    _Entry_point_2_0: while (true)
    {
      // ... some code
      continue (function() { /*...*/ ; return '_Entry_point_2_0'; })();
      // ... some code
    }
  }
```

"Almost" because of two reasons. I still have the problem with labels exactly as before, and what's more now I have problem where to add `break`s to the loop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what this code should accomplish at the end? Right now I have a hard time to understand your question fully and it seems a bit like a XY problem.

Comment: @greenoldman Can your function return true or false? Then you can use it in a while loop: `while(function());`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to make an infinite loop where the lambda continuously re-calls itself?

Comment: I would argue that there **has to** be a way to write that same logic without labels and trying to bend over backwards... PHP missing a comma operator forcing you into impossible situations...? Hmm...

Comment: What is the inside function doing. It seems that can be replaced by a loop ?

Comment: @Rizier123, sure, but I am afraid it could lead to other questions -- I try to translate code to PHP with tail call optimization. So in one step I have to reassign main function parameters and jump to the entry point.

Comment: @Ferrybig, yes, the lambda can return anything, but I cannot put the lambda in the loop, because the main function has to be in (logic) loop, not the lambda.

Comment: @johncorser, sorry for not being clear, I added "some code" comments -- the loop yes, but not over lambda, but over the main function. Or in other words I would like to have `continue` for entire function.

Comment: @exussum, the main function is doing some computations, in the middle there is this lambda I showed, which also does some little computations. As for loop (for main function) it is exactly what I would like to achieve -- however I have to simulate the loop with gotos, because I know when I need to loop again, and other parts of the main function do not know when to break. So I cannot change it to `while/continue/break`.

Comment: So I'd add in your question that you're trying to replace/inject code automatically, and the original code follows a pattern such that it's hard/impossible to replace it with statements, but you can write expressions within the pre-existing statements. Since `goto` or `continue` are control structures (and thus can't work as an expression), however, there's a catch-22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Perhaps you are trying to solving your attemted solution rather than your original problem. This question smells [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/232765).*

```
_Entry_point_2_0:
    // ... some code
    (function() { /*...*/ ;goto _Entry_point_2_0;})();
```

Looks for me like `do while` loop:

```
do {
    // ... some code
} while ((function() { /*...*/ ; return $k !== 0;})());
```

Now applying an anonymous function like that is not allowed. In addition closure parameters need to be explicitly declared. Thus my solution needs to be written like this:

```
$k = 10;
$f = function() use (&$k) { /*...*/ ; return $k !== 0; };
do {
    // some code
} while ( $f() );
```

If you want to have a "comma operator" you just make a function that takes any numbers of argumens and return the last:

```
function begin(){
    return func_get_args()[func_num_args()-1];
}

begin(expression1, expression2, expression3); // ==> result of expression3
```

All of a function arguments gets evaluated so it does the same given that the arguments are not dependent on each other.

Comment: Ok, my original problem is eliminating tail recursive calls :-) I cannot freely put my lambda+jump code, because they could be part of something bigger, also there could be multiple lambda+jump pairs. As for comma operator I do something similar, but because there could be dependency I capture variable references instead of passing them as arguments.

Comment: @greenoldman So this code is supposed to be one generated by a compiler to do TCO?

Comment: @greenoldman Have you looked at the [trampoline](http://commonphp.blogspot.no/2010/12/revision-to-php-tco-trampoline.html) method?

Comment: No, I just wanted to optimize self recursive calls, which could be cheap as nothing. However I think it is impossible in PHP, because function call is an expression, and every iterating construct is a statement, and PHP does not allow to exchange those. Trampoline while more powerful it is also costly.

Answer (score 4):

So you can't skip a loop iteration from within an anonymous/lambda function. But you could return a value, compare values in the main function and then skip the iteration from there. Sounds simple, right?

Edit: if you also want to break from the lamba, you can use the same strategy.

```
function water() {
    $lambda = function() { /*...*/; };

    while (true) {
        // Call the lambda function and store the return value.
        $return = $lambda();

        // If the return value was 'skip this iteration', well... skip it.
        // Note: I'd normally compare to false, null or similar.
        if ($return == 'skip this iteration') {
            continue;
        }
        elseif ($return == "we're done!") {
            break;
        }

        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

> I need to make it in one expression -- execute lambda and goto has to be packed in single expression.

So from your last comment I now partly understand why you have this requirement. But it's still not entirely clear. You have written a script to inject this code into some pre-existing function(s) and don't know the surroundings. But are the goto labels already in place? In any case, perhaps your problem is as simple as this: you want the code to be a single **line** only. But that's possible, code *can* span only a single line in PHP. It's not the prettiest, but it works just fine.

```
function water() {
    while (true) {
        if (function() { /*...*/; }() == 'skip this iteration') { continue; /* Or goto */ }
        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very close, but PHP does not give up :-) I need to make it single expression. I was thinking about such code `my_lambda() ? goto label : goto label`. The logic for me is OK, but `goto` is not expression and ternary operator requires expressions. I cannot use `if` because they are statements.

Comment: I'm saying you *shouldn't* use goto in the first place. I still don't see the reason to use it

Comment: This is what I came to when trying to rewrite tail recursive call. So I am doing tail recursive call optimization here, I don't see any other option.

Comment: Did you even try my answer? From your question it's clear that you have control over what the lambda returns. So if you want to jump (using either evil `goto` or proper `continue`/`break`) then you need to encode that as an instruction in the return value of the lambda and compare it in the main function. I can't really search for the missing piece of the puzzle if you don't provide more information.

Comment: What good does insult do? Of course I read you answer and I also explained why I cannot use it. It is very close to the solution I am looking for, but as for now I cannot use (I need "jump + lambda" to be single expression).

Comment: I'm sorry if that was insulting, I'm just confused why it doesn't work for you so I had to ask if you tried. Why exactly do you need it to be 1 expression? Why can't it be an if? It **can't** be 1 expression because continue (and goto for that matter) need to be their own statement.

Comment: By single expression I mean (imaginary code) "goto compute_label()" so it could be theoretically used as sub-expression. The problem is I rewrite (automatically) regular tail recursive calls into looped versions so I don't know the surroundings. All I see there is tail recursive call, so I add entry point, I reassign parameters and add that `goto`. At least I try :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107320/discussion-between-aross-and-greenoldman).

Answer (score 1):

Im fairly sure this is impossible by design.

[Annonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)  require all "state" to be passed in via a use statement. You can not pass a label as a reference

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '_Entry_point_2_0'
>   (T_STRING), expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

The function is running in its own scope with no reference to the label which means it would need to be passed back somehow.

[goto docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) have the following

```
This is not a full unrestricted goto. The target label must be within the same file and context, meaning that you cannot jump out of a function or method, nor can you jump into one.
```

its also invalid to pass a variable to goto

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$goto' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Though all of this is probably a good thing, as goto suggests the logic flow is wrong, You will be able to find a way to structure this that is more corect and does not require a go to.

Edit:

After update 2 why not do

```
 if(your lambda() == something) {
        Continue;
 }
```

Sorry wrote the code on my phone. That seems to do the same thing and is much more readable

Comment: No problem with phone :-) Thank you for your help. I know about the limitations of goto, that is why I am asking how to somehow do the magic. As for the `continue` -- I would need to add `break`s which is not trivial, but worse I still have the problem with labels and single expression. `if` is a statement.

Comment: @greenoldman labels are not strings! label is a user defined keyword, and there is no dynamic label definition in php check this to understand limitations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702297/dynamic-jump-to-label-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
function myFunc($i = 0) {
    if ($i < 10) { //or any other logic to prevent "infinite loop"
        //Main code
        myFunc($i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, generally I can but it is not my need -- I have to "translate" recursive call to manual loop of the inner body of the function. That is the whole point.