# C, get the memory segment given the pointer

Tags: c, gdb

Is it possible to get memory segment given a pointer / immidiate address value.

Is there a solution already avaliable in GDB ?.
If not a custom gcc (non portable) function implementation should be good too.

Ex :

```
int data = 100;
int main(void) {
   int ldata = 100;
   int *hdata = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
}

getMemSeg(&data)  should return "DATA"
getMemSeg(&ldata) should return "STACK"
getMemSeg(hdata)  should return "HEAP"
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken those are just labels. This looks relevant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777990/c-programming-address-of-a-label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read `/proc/self/maps` to see the details of the memory layout of the process. A C library has a symbol which indicates the beginning of the heap. In glibc it's calles `_end`. And anything on the stack is always below anyting in the current stack frame (at least in x86 and other processors where the stack grows downwards). So at least for a simple program these heuristics would work:

```
extern int _end;

const char* getMemSeg(void* p){
   int stackframe;
   if(p>(void*)&stackframe)
      return "STACK";
   if(p<(void*)&_end)
      return "DATA";
   return "HEAP";
}
```