# why does gcc uses && unary operator instead of giving direct address of a label?

Tags: c, gcc, unary-operator

I had this doubt that why does gcc uses `&&` to access a label and why it doesn't directly gives access to the value of location associated with the label. like in the following piece of code :

```
void main()
{
    static void* loc = &&locA;
    printf("locA : %p\n", locA); //will give error
    printf("loc : %p\n",loc); //will not give error
    //statments X
    locA :
    //statements Y

}
```

Comment: You might find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777990/is-it-possible-to-store-the-address-of-a-label-in-a-variable-and-use-goto-to-jum The TL;DR is probably: because obtaining the address of a label isn't supported by the C and C++ standards.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even know gcc could do this. As far as I know MSVC doesn't support this -- not that I've really used `goto` much, but still good to know now!

Comment: @Blindy : If using MSVC in 32 bit code (not x64) you can access the label's address with inline assembly.  `void* loc; __asm{ mov [loc],offset locA }; locA:`

Comment: I have to agree with @Olaf 's opinion though - if you have to use a non standard compliant way of doing something, you might be better off reworking your code to find a standard compliant way of achieving the same goal.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gcc extension as document [Extensions to the C Language Family of the gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) in the section [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) which says:

> You can get the address of a label defined in the current function (or
>   a containing function) with the unary operator ‘&&’. The value has
>   type void *. This value is a constant and can be used wherever a
>   constant of that type is valid. For example:
>
> ```
>  void *ptr;
>  /* ... */
>  ptr = &&foo;
> ```
>
> To use these values, you need to be able to jump to one. This is done
>   with the computed goto statement1, goto *exp;. For example,
>
> ```
>  goto *ptr;
> ```
>
> One way of using these constants is in initializing a static array
>   that serves as a jump table:
>
> ```
>  static void *array[] = { &&foo, &&bar, &&hack };
> ```
>
> Then you can select a label with indexing, like this:
>
> ```
>  goto *array[i];
> ```