# Is there any template usage can optimize out the branch?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++14

The class `A` has a template member function `A::runImpl`. The function `A::run` calls a specialized implementation based on the value of `A::m_case`, which is set within the class constructor.

In my project, the `run` function is called very frequently. It will speedup over 5% if the branch within it can be eliminated. Is there any template usage can do this?
My project is compiled by GCC 7.3.1 with C++14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  A (uint32_t * arr, size_t len) : m_case(0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      m_case += arr[i];
    }
  }

  template <size_t> void runImpl() { assert(0); };
  void run();

private:
  size_t m_case;
};

template <>
inline void A::runImpl<0>() {
  cout << "Default execution path." << endl;
}

template <>
inline void A::runImpl<1>() {
  cout << "Optimized execution path 1." << endl;
}

template <>
inline void A::runImpl<2>() {
  cout << "Optimized execution path 2." << endl;
}

void A::run() {
  switch (m_case) {
    case 1:
      runImpl<1>();
      break;
    case 2:
      runImpl<2>();
      break;
    default:
      runImpl<0>();
      break;
  }
}

int main() {
  uint32_t arr[] = {1, 1};
  A a(arr, 2);
  a.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `m_case` something that will be known at compile time or can it be set at runtime?

Comment: Some template trick would require compile time constants. Is the array provided to the constructor `constexpr`? If not, you are caught in runtime already and templates are out. You *could* then, though, do the switch-case already in the constructor and store the address of the function to be called in a member function pointer. Then `run` would just call the function stored in there.

Comment: @NathanOliver The `m_case` is the sum of an arrary, which is an arg. of the constructor.

Comment: Yes, but is that a value you will know at compile time?  It is in your example but that might just be because it's example code.

Comment: @NathanOliver The value is determined during runtime.

Comment: You might trade switch case with function pointer, but branch prediction is generally better than jump predictor...

Comment: @Aconcagua In the way you sugguested, the branch will goes to a function call. In my example, all implementations of `runImpl` are `inline`. I have tested that a function call within `run` is more expensive then branch presented in my example.

Comment: Okay.  I will throw my hat in with the other and suggest you use a function pointer and call the function through the pointer.  It may or may not give you an improvement.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938518/how-to-store-goto-labels-in-an-array-and-then-jump-to-them) might be pretty interesting for you – though you rely on a non-standard solution then. Have an array with three labels to jump to and add `m_state = m_state > 3 ? 0 : m_state;` to your constructor...

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 0):

## Non-portable solution!!!

You can try to optimise with your own jump table (adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938555/1312382)); this relies on a *non-standard* feature of GCC (and clang) that allows to take the address of a label; to be able to profit from you need to make sure that `m_state` is within proper range of [0; 2], so you would add

```
m_state = m_state < 3 ? m_state : 0;
```

to your constructor (or use a separate variable, if you still need the original value for other purposes).

Then your `run` function can look like this:

```
void A::run()
{
    static void* levels[] = { &&LEVEL0, &&LEVEL1, &&LEVEL2 };
    goto *levels[m_state];

    LEVEL0:
    runImpl<0>();
    return;
    LEVEL1:
    runImpl<1>();
    return;
    LEVEL2:
    runImpl<2>();
    return;
}
```

If this is indeed faster than your current switch/case solution you need to measure on your own...

Demonstration on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nr5T434hE).

To still retain portability you might detect the compiler according to [this site](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/j/guide-to-predefined-macros-in-c-compilers-gcc-clang-msvc-etc..html) and enable this optimisation for those compilers you know support it and fall back to the switch statement for the others.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `cmov` instruction to avoid using branches. However, `cmov` doesn't necessarily make your code run faster. I tried running your code with/without the `cmove` instruction and interestingly, the use of `cmov` degrades performance.

> Without `cmov`:
> Optimized execution path 2.
> ->**Time: 0.000029**

> With `cmov`:
> Optimized execution path 2.
> ->**Time: 0.000038**

Try compiling your code with/without these flags to enable/disable using `cmov`:

```
-O3 -g -fno-if-conversion -fno-if-conversion2 -fno-tree-loop-if-convert -fno-tree-loop-if-convert-stores -fno-inline
```